# Database suggestions for storing a "count" for every hour of the day

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have had an online archive service for over a year now. Unfortunately, I didn't put in the infrastructure to keep statistics. All I have now are the archive access logs.

For every hour there are two audio files (0-30 min in one and 30-60 min in other). I've currently used MySQL to put in the counts. Looks something like this:

```
|     DATE     |   TIME  | COUNT |
|  2012-06-12  |  20:00  |  39   |
|  2012-06-12  |  20:30  |  26   |
|  2012-06-12  |  21:00  |  16   |
```

and so on...

That makes 365 days * 24 hrs * 2 (2 halves in an hour) > 17500 rows. This makes read/write slow and I feel a lot of space is wasted storing it this way.

So do you know of any other database that will store this data more efficiently and is faster?

Comment: 17500 is not a lot.  And you can store the date and time in one column as a DATETIME.  If it is slow to read, consider adding an index to the DATETIME.

Comment: Worry when you reach billions of rows. 175k is quite small, considering there's databases with literally trillions of rows.

Comment: @Michael Right. I could use indexes. But there isn't any way to shorten the write times, is there?

Comment: @Marc Oh haha. Clearly I had no idea. But just out of curiosity are there other db's that can store it in a better way?

Comment: @Ram if the write times are slow, it is likely because of the time it takes to seek to the row you need (hence the index) or because you have more throughput than you can deal with. If it's a question of throughput, then don't store the counts in real time.  Instead store the log as you always have, and use a nightly script to compile the stats.

Comment: `DATETIME` takes 8 Bytes, `INT` takes 4 Bytes. So that is 12B * 17,500 = ~`200kB` in a year. That doesn't seem like much of a waste of space to me considering you could store about 7 years worth of data on a floppy disk

Comment: You must either be storing something else in those tables besides the three mentioned rows (Big BLOB of audio file perhaps?) - or you either have a misconfigured database or a seriously underpowered server.
Even with 17500 rows and NO indexes, scanning tha whole table would be very close to instant.
If you are storing BLOBs along with the data I would suggest to simply seperate the BLOB data into a dedicated table, or consider storing the files on disk, and only store the filename in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not too many rows. If it's properly indexed, reads should be pretty fast (writes will be a little slower, but even with tables of up to about half a million rows I hardly notice).

If you are selecting items from the database using something like

`select * from my_table where date='2012-06-12'`

Then you need to make sure that you have an index on the date column. You can also create multiple column indexes if you are using more than one column in your where statement. That will make your read statements very fast (like I said up to on the order of a million rows).

If you're unacquainted with indexes, see here:

[MySQL Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)